# PL/SQL: is there an instruction to completely stop the script execution?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exit-code

I'm trying to do some checkings on a DB schema at the beginning of a PL/SQL script.

If the checkings give unsuccessful results, I want to stop the script, to prevent the next instructions to be executed.

I got something like this

```
-- 1st line of PL/SQL script

DECLARE
  SOME_COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO SOME_COUNT FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE <SOME_CONDITIONS>;
  IF (SOME_COUNT > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test failed, I don''want the rest of the script'
      || ' to be executed.');
    --EXIT or something like that?... <= STOP EXECUTION HERE
  END IF;
END;
/

-- OTHER SQL INSTRUCTIONS...
ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE ...
```

I'm looking for the instruction(s) allowing to do the "`STOP EXECUTION HERE`".

Comment: Are you really talking about a PL/SQL script?  Or a SQL*Plus script?  You can't have a DDL statement in PL/SQL (unless you put it in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`).  So it appears to me that you're talking about a SQL*Plus script.  If you are talking about a SQL*Plus script, if the PL/SQL block errors out, SQL*Plus will by default continue executing the next SQL statement (or PL/SQL block) in the script.  You'd need to use the SQL*Plus command `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Justin. In fact I'm not an "Oracle Expert", even if I have good knowledge of DBMS in general. Therefore I didn't yet grasp the difference between PL/SQL or SQL*Plus scripts (do you know some blog/doc/site explaining clearly that difference?). All that I can tell is that I'm using **Navicat**, using the "query" pane and load my script file into it. In that specific context, `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR()` does the job.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question shows a multi-statement batch script. RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR() only exits out of a PL/SQL block (sub-program), not out of the overall script (as pointed out by Justin) so it will continue with statements that follow.

For batch scripts, it is best to use WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT. Yes, it is a SQL*Plus directive, not standard SQL, but is fairly portable; most popular Oracle tools that support scripts support this directive, at least partially. The following example works in SQL*Plus, SQL*Developer, Toad, SQLsmith and possibly others, and demonstrates the problem, if you comment the line out.

```
set serveroutput on

-- Without this line, things keep going
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;

BEGIN
  IF (1 > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First thing');
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Test failed'); -- not enough
  END IF;
END;
/

-- This will execute if you remove WHEN SQLERROR.., so RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is not enough
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Second thing - Executes anyway');
END;
/
```

If you remove the WHEN SQLERROR, the script will continue and execute the 2nd block, etc. which is exactly what the question asks to avoid.

The advantage, in this instance, of graphical tools that emulate sqlplus, is that they really stop the script and don't submit the remainder of the script to the command shell as shell commands, which is what happens if you paste scripts into SQL*Plus running in a console window. SQL*Plus may exit on error, but the remaining buffered commands will then be handled by the OS shell, which is a bit messy and potentially risky, if you had shell commands in the comments (which isn't unheard of). With SQLPlus, it is always best to connect, and then execute the script, or pass it in the < start > command line argument (sqlplus scott/tiger @foo.sql) to avoid this.

Comment: +1 this really helped. I knew about exceptions and application errors but I need to do one precondition check in a DDL script that should stop the script. The alternative (doing DDL in an IF statement in a PL/SQL script) isn't very enticing.

Comment: You might want to remove 'disagree with the accepted answer'

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to raise an exception, you could try something like (untested):

```
declare
  SOME_COUNT INTEGER;
begin
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO SOME_COUNT FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE <SOME_CONDITIONS>;
  IF (SOME_COUNT > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test failed, I don''want the rest of the script'
      || ' to be executed.');

    goto end_proc;
  END IF;

  -- A bunch of great code here

  <<end_proc>>
  null;  -- this could be a commit or other lines of code
end;
```

Some people hate any GOTO statements as they can lead to spaghetti code if abused, but in simple situations like this (again, assuming you don't want to raise an exception) they work well imo.

Comment: Thanks, +1. The only problem I see, is that I've a lot of DDL statements (`ALTER TABLE`...) as `bunch of great code`, requiring to use a lot the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` workaround, consequently the script code would be less readable/maintainable.

Comment: Yeah, thats a different problem than your OP, but I agree that some code out there is far from "great" ;-)  That comment was a bit tongue in cheek, but again the point was to give an alternate solution for your question.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than throw an application error, it's much simpler to just use the [`RETURN` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems040.htm) which exits the current PL/SQL block very smoothly.

Just make sure you do a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exited because <error')` before it to provide the user with a nice message of why you're exiting of course!

Comment: NB: As written, Here we only exit the current block... **not the full script**.

Comment: Yes very true. Sorry about that. I would argue that any code which depends on the code before it should be in the same block, though.